# how to read external digital input in android?

Tags: android

Are there anyway to read digital signal input using android device? is it possible with USB cable or any other app ?

there is a sensor to get count of products in production floor. We need to get that counting signal into android device when products are going through the sensor.

we saw some ways like IOIO, arduino. But we need to just read the input with not goigng such a big development hardware or software

Thanks a lot for any idea

Answer (score 0):

check out protocoder http://www.protocoder.org It has a really good support for ioio boards. Pretty easy to use and no need to install anything in your computer :)